# Rails 4 - Name Of Current Layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've found numerous resources for Rails 3, but none for Rails 4:

---

In an effort to keep things DRY, we have a method which defines some meta tags. I'd like to include the layout in the `title` param:

```
  #app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  before_action :set_meta_tags

  def set_meta_tags
    title = (layout != "application") ? "#{layout} ::" : false
    set_meta title: "#{layout} #{setting(:site, :title)}", description: setting(:site, :description)
  end
```

Only problem is I don't know how to return the current layout in Rails 4 - any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Rails 5, the code is:

```
controller.send :_layout, ["some_string_here"]
```

I don't know why it needs a string in the array but that's what got it working for me. Our helper file looks as follows:

```
def current_layout
  layout = controller.send :_layout, ["test"]
  return layout.inspect.split("/").last.gsub(/.haml/,"")
end
```

Comment: This fails in Rails 6 which requires two arguments for the _layout method.

Answer (score 11):

For me in Rails 6 the `current_layout` method would look like this

```
def current_layout
  self.controller.send :_layout, self.lookup_context, []
end
```

I believe the array is a list of formats used. The method `_layout` is build dynamically and I'm not sure what it's expecting in the `formats` parameter, but I got my desired behaviour with just an empty array
Hope this helps.

Comment: This almost worked for me with Rails 6.1. I did have to put a value in the formats excepted, like so: `self.controller.send :_layout, self.lookup_context, [:html]`

Comment: Be aware, that layouts can also be `Proc`s.

Answer (score 7):

You can add the following `helper method` in `ApplicationHelper`:

```
def current_layout
     (controller.send :_layout).inspect.split("/").last.gsub(/.html.erb/,"") 
end
```

And you can call it accordingly in `set_meta_tags` method. Something like,

```
  def set_meta_tags
    title = (current_layout != "application") ? "#{current_layout} ::" : false
    set_meta title: "#{layout} #{setting(:site, :title)}", description: setting(:site, :description)
  end
```

**NOTE:**

`.inspect` gives me the layout name with its relative path.

`.split("/").last` will remove the relative path and returns just the layout name(with extension).

`.gsub(/.html.erb/)` removes the extension part of layout. You may need to adjust the `extension` based on the template engine you are using e.g. In case of Haml use `.html.haml`.

---

**My Solution**

From a chat with Kirti, it seems that my forgetting to mention we had manually set out `layout` was a big deal. This will work if you manually set your layout:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def current_layout
   self.send :_layout
end

def set_meta_tags
    title  = (current_layout != "application") ? "#{current_layout.titleize} :: " : ""
    set_meta title: title + setting(:site, :title), description: setting(:site, :description)
end
```

Comment: Spasibo! Let me try it out

Comment: Actually, hold on it didn't work so well - let me debug